# Referencing Images with Database on firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm doing a small Android e-commerce project while learning FireBase and I wanted to call an image when I get the details of it via the console. I was wondering if I could do both of the at the same time and give the output where the entire product can be viewed.

I've already searched all over the internet and could not find a solution to this problem. The structure will be somewhat like amazon apps products page.